# multiple image upload to different column php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

good day , here i have a page that store data with some images in it , 3 images to be exact,

```html
    <?php 
    $brg            = $_POST['id'];
    $nama           = $_POST['nm'];
    $img            = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $tmp            = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $img1           = $_FILES['img1']['name'];
    $tmp1           = $_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'];
    $img2           = $_FILES['img2']['name'];
    $tmp2           = $_FILES['img2']['tmp_name'];

    $temp           = explode(".", $img);
    $temp1          = explode(".", $img1);
    $temp2          = explode(".", $img2);
    $new            = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    $new1           = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp1);
    $new2           = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp2);
    $path           = "img/photo/".$new;
    $path1          = "img/photo/".$new1;
    $path2          = "img/photo/".$new2;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp1, $path1);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp2, $path2);

$c  = "insert into imgstuff values('$brg','$nama','$new','$new1','$new2');";

$ins=mysqli_query($con,$c);

if($ins){
header('location: test.php?success='.base64_encode('success'));
} else {
header('location: test.php?error='.base64_encode('failed'));
}
?>
```

code above works perfectly but as you can see it ends up horribly ugly and it produce same file name for three picture ,

my question, is there any ways to made my code cleaner and easy to maintain and whats wrong with my naming files method ?

Comment: Use a loop so there is less repeated code and use prepared statements - this is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: 'same file name' means? You can set unique names before uploading the files.

Comment: Get files in an array from html and just process it in loop. Thats it.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala yes , in database the filename ends up with something like "12121.jpg" , "12121.jpg" , "12121.jpg"

Comment: @xcloox Exactly! because all files have the same name `12121.jpg`

Comment: You ought to post the full code as there are variables above that are not defined `$img,$img1,$img2`

Comment: @RamRaider ah yes my bad , already added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use a loop so that you do not repeat code unnecessarily and definitely to use `prepared statements` to avoid nasty unpleasantness from `sql injection attacks`

As for the `new image` name - there are many ways in which you can achieve a new, unique name - the method here is not necessarily going to be unique but it does at least incorporate the original filename so of the three images they should be unique. None of the below is tested btw but it might give you some ideas.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['id'], $_POST['nm'] ){

        $files=array();

        $sql='insert into `imgstuff` values (?,?,?,?,?)';
        $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            for( $i=0; $i < 3; $i++ ){

                $obj = $i==0 ? (object)$_FILES[ 'img' ] : (object)$_FILES[ 'img' . $i ];
                $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
                $name=$obj->name;

                $ext = pathinfo( $name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                $new = round( microtime( true ) ) . '_' . $name . '.' . $ext;

                $path = "img/photo/$new";
                $status = is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) & move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $path );
                if( $status ) $files[] = $path;
            }

            if( count( $files )==count( $imgs ) ){

                $brg  = $_POST['id'];
                $nama = $_POST['nm'];

                $stmt->bind_param( 'issss', $brg, $nama, $files[0], $files[1], $files[2] );
                $stmt->execute();

                $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
                $message=$rows!=0 ? 'success' : 'failed';

                header('location: test.php?success=' . base64_encode( $message ) );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
```

return the same things because it's done almost at the same time. Can you try something like uuid or even a simple function such as

```
function getUniqFileName($end) {
    $token = md5(sha1(rand()));

    return sprintf($token%s, $end);
}
```

and then in your code

```
$new = getUniqFileName(end($temp));
```

That will give you a bit more uniq name very quickly ?

(Edit : removed the round which is quite useless in this case)

Comment: Why make it so complex? Simply upload it using loop.